# PHP. Sort players Top 10 board and add numbering

Tags: php, xml

I'm creating flash game. There are TOP 10 players board, but I need to correct It a little bit.
I need to sort to 1 column user names and to other time and second thing what I need add numbering to names.
Here is example what I need:
[image: vision]

Ok here what I have:

Here is top.php

```
<?php 
    $time = $_POST['time'];     
    session_start();
    $name = $_SESSION['vardas']; 
    $time = strtotime($time);
    $times = date('s:H:i', $time);
    $_SESSION['test'] = $times;
    $_SESSION['test1'] = $username;


    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_db","pass","my_db");

    $query = "SELECT userName,time FROM eurokos ORDER by time ASC LIMIT 10";
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
//    printf(" ", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}
 header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    echo '<results>';
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo $row["userName"].' '.$row["time"]."\n"; //here is line which I need
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    echo '</results>';
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

I don't have idea how to sort this data to 2 different collumns, I need your help with It.

But about numbering I know I need to add `for` somewhere here:

```
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               echo $row["userName"].' '.$row["time"]."\n"; //here is line which I need
            }
```

But I need your help to did that correct. Thank you very much.

**UPDATED:**
When I use this:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $rank = 1;
    echo '<table>';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>'.$rank.' '.$row["userName"].'</td><td>'.$row["time"].'</td>'; 
       $rank++;
       echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    $result->free();
}
```

How It looks like now:

[image]

And here is my top.php

http://padekime.eu/top.php

Comment: So you don't know how to concatenate strings ? Also, this is php, not actionscript.

Comment: I updated my question what happened when I used @RST method.

Comment: @RST has thought that you need an HTML table. Omit every tag in the code like '<table>' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $rank = 1;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo '<player><playername>'.$rank.' '.$row["userName"].'</playername><playertime>'.$row["time"].'</playertime></player>'; 
       $rank++;
    }
    $result->free();
}
```

You can control the output by CSS

```
player
{
   display: block;
}
playername
{
//settings here;
}
playertime
{
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: I thought you were displaying HTML, overlooked your xml tag

Comment: If you don't want to use any tags you will have to calculate the length of rank + playername + time. Decide how many characters could be on one line and add whitespace for the difference.

Comment: Thank you for answer and how my ccs should look like for that simple result?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? I have adjusted the code. This is the minimum you need. Save it to a file and load the file just before `<results>`. Use Google first, if you get stuck.

Comment: When I use `include 'top.css'; ... echo '<player><playername>'.$rank. '. ' .$row["userName"].'</playername> <playertime>'.$row["time"].'</playertime></player>'."\n";`
I got XML error: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>player
--------------------------------------^`

Comment: Yes, I can understand that. That is not the way to include a CSS file with XML.`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="your_file_name.css"?>`. In future questions you have to put more effort in finding a solution. Google what you need. Otherwise people will not be willing to help. This is not a question and asnwer forum.